# Why should I upgrade my Django 1.5 app to Django 1.8?

Tags: django, version, upgrade

What are the unmissable features that I'll be missing out on by sticking around with Django 1.5.

Answer (score 6):

It's not even a question of that. 1.5 is *unsupported*: no security updates have been made to it since the release of 1.7. There have already been several security issues raised and fixed since then, which you are missing.

Comment: Here you will find the overview of which version is supported until when (scroll down a bit): https://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of the `DurationField` which is modeled in Python by `timedelta`. You can see a full list of features [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/)